# Org async export show pdf after completion

Tags: org-mode, org-export, async

With synchronous export I can call `C-c C-e l o` to generate a pdf and open it. If I try the same keys with the async export, i.e. `C-c C-e C-a l o`, then the pdf will be generated but the pdf won't open.

How can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: I don't think that this is easily possible. There is an option to list the asynchronously generated files (with `C-u C-u C-c C-e`), but that's not what you want. You could report this as a bug as it is a deviation from expected behaviour.